# uname -a displays "Linux 4.19.0-9-amd64". What option of uname or other command will display that I'm using Debian 10.4?

Tags: bash

I know the command that displays my *Linux* version :

```bsh
$ uname -a
Linux bouleau 4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1 (2020-06-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What option of `uname` or order command will tell me that I'm using `Debian 10.4` ?

Comment: Is `lsb_release -a` what you're looking for?

Comment: It only displays `Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)`, not the minor version number. Someone designated me an iso file : `debian-live-10.4.0-amd64-cinnamon.iso`. I want to check what version of Debian I currently own, with that same numbers.

Comment: The only other one I've got (I have no Debian systems running right now) is `cat /etc/*-release`. That one may show your minor version, as it has more info.

Comment: A higher minor version number only means that you use a newer method of installation. All 10.x installations will give you the same system after a `apt-get update && apt-get full-upgrade`

Comment: @Garo Interresting. Do you have a source explaining this ?

Comment: @Marc I’m not sure there’s any “official” documentation explicitly drawing this conclusion, but it’s the result of the way the repositories are handled: they don’t distinguish between point releases, they only provide the latest packages in any given suite (wheezy, buster, etc.). Thus when you install any given point-release, the next upgrade (which is usually performed during the installation) will upgrade to the latest point-release.